# Existence of a (weak) antiderivative for any given $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be an integrable function. Then, I wonder if there exists any integrable $F : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\nabla F = f
\end{equation}
where $\nabla F$ is understood as the weak gradient on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For $n=1$, it seems quite straightforward by integration on the real line. However, I do not see how I can extend to $n>1$. Could anyone help me?

Comment: First of all, the curl of $f$ will still have to vanish in a weak sense... and if that curl indeed vanishes, the anti-derivative may turn out to be not in $L_1$.

Comment: Path dependence of the line integral is going to be a problem (which is the curl issue mentioned above).

Comment: @Vergilius Much worse than I ever imagined..... Is the antiderivative at least locally $L^1$?